# Peek() never evaluating to negative one

Tags: c#, while-loop

I'm learning C and C#, this question is for C#. I have this while loop and it is resulting in a infinite loop. I have used this before and it always worked great. But now it just loops forever and never exits. I'm doing this while loop to count the number of lines in the file.

Here is the code:

```
                using (TextReader obj2 = new StreamReader(combined))
                {
                    int count = 1;
                    while (obj2.Peek() != -1)
                    {
                        count++;
                    }
                    obj2.Close();
                    TextWriter obj = File.AppendText(combined);
                    Console.Write("How many lines do you want to add to the file?:");
                    int numberOfLines = 0;
                    int lineNumer = count + 1;
                    numberOfLines = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++)
                    {
                        Console.Write("Enter a line of text:");
                        string line = Console.ReadLine();
                        obj.WriteLine(lineNumer + ". " + line);
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Peek()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.textreader.peek%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) doesn't advanced the reader. You need to make a call to `obj2.Read()` inside your loop, or it will never terminate as you've seen.

From the linked MSDN reference:

> Reads the next character without changing the state of the reader or
>   the character source. Returns the next available character without
>   actually reading it from the reader.

See also [`Read()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w3csw16%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN.

These two methods work hand-in-hand quite often so that you can check if the stream has ended without affecting it. You're on the right track!